# Kivy Graph blinks and duplicate on initializing

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, kivy

**BUG DESCRIPTION**
I am working on simple kivy project to display graphs but as I initialized the graph with some data points and run the app, I get two graphs one originally configured graph and the second mini graph just below the original one and as I maximize the screen size, the mini graph start to blink.

To debug this problem, I created a simple kivy application having only one widget graph and initialized the graph with simple tuples as can be seen in the code below. But still having the same problem, so I am wondering that If its module issue.

**To Reproduce**
Here is the code for simple graph application in kivy.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy_garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot


class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root = FloatLayout()
        graph = Graph(
            xlabel='TIME',
            ylabel='POWER',
            # x_ticks_minor=5,
            # x_ticks_major=25,
            # y_ticks_major=1,
            y_grid_label=True,
            x_grid_label=True,
            padding=5,
            x_grid=True,
            y_grid=True,
            xmin=-0,
            xmax=19,
            ymin=0,
            ymax=11,
            size_hint=(0.8, 0.75),
            pos_hint={'x': 0, 'y': 0.15},
        )

        plot = MeshLinePlot(mode='line_strip', color=[0.9, 0.6, 0.3, 1])
        plot.points = [
            (0, 10),
            (1, 9.5),
            (2, 9.8),
            (3, 9.3),
            (4, 9.9),
            (5, 9.8),
            (6, 9.4),
            (7, 9.2),
            (8, 9.2),
            (9, 9.5),
            (10, 9.6),
            (11, 9.1),
            (12, 9.7),
            (13, 9.5),
            (14, 9.5),
            (15, 9.4),
            (16, 9.9),
            (17, 10),
            (18, 9.6),
        ]
        graph.add_plot(plot)
        root.add_widget(graph)
        return root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**Platform**

- OS: Windows 10
- Python version: 3.6.7
- Kivy version: 1.11.1
- Kivy garden graph version: 0.4.dev0

I didn't get any warning or error messages in log.